# Can I use an LGA 1156/1155 heatsink on an LGA 1150 motherboard?

Tags: motherboard, cooling, heatsink

I'm considering moving to Haswell from Nehalem by just getting a new mobo and CPU, but I'm not sure if I can keep my current heatsink.

Can an LGA 1156 heatsink be mounted on to an LGA 1150 motherboard?

Edit: I just read 1156 heatsinks fit 1155 motherboards, so I guess the question is also can I go from 1155 to 1150?

Comment: What's the heatsink in question here?

Comment: @happy_soil I've had it so long that had to look it up on my Newegg order history, and wow! It's actually this LGA775 [Scythe SCINF-1000](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16835185027), with an adapter to LGA 1156 also by Scythe.

Comment: @Louis - It should indeed work.  The best people to answer it though is the manufacture.

Comment: @Ramhound Okay, so the mounts are generally unchanged for the past few years? That would be great news.

Comment: @Louis - First check to see if they have an adapter and see what it says. Second the previous 2 generation layouts were not changed.  But Nahalem is 3 generations ago isn't it?  Again best way to get a 100% accurate answer would be to ask the manufacture.  Can you link to the adapater?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I edited the question because after reading your coment I found that it was also unchanged from first to second gen.

Comment: @Louis - 1155 is Ivy Bridge my Heatsink was a Ivy Bridge heatsink its installed on a Hawell motherboard.  Be sure you post an answer with supporting documentation you can take the credit :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I can't find an authoritative reference (ie. from manufacturers), there is a definitive "yes" around the internet.

There are many posts on many forums confirming that 1156/1155/1150 are compatible. Examples at: [overclock.net](http://www.overclock.net/t/1241107/socket-1155-coolers-compatible-with-socket-1150-haswell), [Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1703568/lga-1155-cooler-fit-lga-1150-socket.html), [guru3d](http://forums.guru3d.com/showthread.php?t=378975).

What I noticed myself when Haswell first came out: existing coolers (such as the [Noctua NH-D14](http://www.noctua.at/main.php?show=productview&products_id=34&lng=en&set=1), as an example) had their specification details updated to include 1150, but they're still the same cooler.

And, if you accept an unreferenced statement on Wikipedia as a reference :o, the [socket 1150](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1150) entry says:

> Cooling systems for LGA 1155 and LGA 1156 sockets are compatible with
>   LGA 1150, due to them having the same distance of 75 mm between each
>   screw hole.

Comment: Fits fine and working well.